# Unity very high memory usage while compiling

Tags: c#, memory, unity-game-engine

Some weird thing started a yesterday on my unity project and I can't seem to resolve.
My code works fully functional with no memory leaks, etc, but since yesterday, I'm unable to test my game using the "Play" button. Here's what happens:

[image]

As you can see, Unity is sucking 2 GB (a massive amount) on compiling and just crashing by lack of memory.

Already tried on different pc's and still no result.
Removing all GameObjects from scene solves the problem, but adding anything (Even scriptless) starts all over again.

Feel free to ask for more details, since I'm kinda like to forget important infos.

Comment: Mate, profinity is profanity, even when it's hidden behind stupid SciFi references :-)

Comment: I found that'stupid' offensive :C

Comment: Markus, it wasn't directed against you, it was directed against Galactica, a series I'll always regret devoting time to because of the bizarre ending they chose. I perhaps should have made it clearer that it was a "stupid SciFi" reference rather than a stupid "SciFi reference". No insult intended (to you, anyway).

Comment: Oh god you called Galactica stupid </3. Just kiddin :)